# SharedPreferences TextView

Tags: android

I have button, after I click button it will list to the ListView, choose ListView item and this item will display to left of the button, I want after I restart the program the listItem was choosed is display.
If anybody know this, please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible simple ways:

1. SharedPreference (simplest)
2. SQLite (maybe for your purpose is useless)

If you have to save only text chosen from a spinner, well, SharedPreference could be the solution. This is how to use it:

READING VALUE from your PREFERENCES_LIST

```
// set name of your preferences list
private static String MY_PREFERENCES = "my_preferences_list";

// set key for retrieving text you saved
private static String TEXT_DATA_KEY = "last_text_spinner_choise";


// create a pointer to your preferences list specifying name and access typology
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// get String from preferences list specifying KEY of Text you want retrieve and a default string if key doesn't exist
String textData = prefs.getString(TEXT_DATA_KEY, "No Preferences!");

// your textView or something else
TextView outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputData); 

// set textView with value taken from your preference list
outputView.setText(textData);
```

WRITING VALUE in your PREFERENCES_LIST

```
// Same as before
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// Editor pointer for changing value in your preference list
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

// your editText or spinner from which you want take text value
EditText outputView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputData);
CharSequence textData = outputView.getText();

if (textData != null) {

   // Here you save textData in your preferences_list. You have to specify key and value. Key is important for retrieving text as seen before
   editor.putString(TEXT_DATA_KEY, textData.toString());
   // Confirm your choice by commit()
   editor.commit();
}
```

Hope it helps